# is there a relationship between an application pool and a windows service

Tags: asp.net, service, iis-6, application-pool

I have a website in IIS 6 (on Windows 2003 Server) that has an application pool that keeps crashing because of too many unhandled exceptions being thrown by some processes. These exceptions are related to a windows service that executes every five minutes. Every time the service runs i get the below warning in the system log (in event viewer):

> A process serving application pool
>   'AppPool1' suffered a fatal
>   communication error with the World
>   Wide Web Publishing Service. The
>   process id was '4172'. The data field
>   contains the error number.

(to note: I also get two errors in the application log, one which displays the stack trace and the second which displays the EventType)

I am trying to recreate this exact scenario in another website (on the same server) so that I can attempt to catch the exception in a development environment and then apply the working code to the live environment. I have created a second service, a second application pool, etc. My problem is that I cannot cause the same warning above for the second application pool (i.e. AppPool2). I have the theory that my second service is somehow connected to my first application pool (AppPool1) but have been unable to prove or confirm this.

My question is, am I right? Is there some sort of "connection/relationship" between the windows service and the application pool (i.e. can i configure a service to access a certain application pool)? If so, how would I configure this? If not, then I am wondering if is it possible that a process from my second service is accessing my first application pool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Application pools are isolated processes.  Your Windows Service process should not affect an application pool process unless it shares a vital resource to that process(like a file...etc), thus causes it to crash.

It sounds like your Windows Service is calling a Web Service in your application or maybe the same resource on the server as your application?